# To fill or not to fill array of structures at the declaration

Tags: c++, arrays, binary-search

I want to read information from a .txt file and store it in an array of structures. I've done it easily in python just to check how to do it and it will be something like this:

`{'Lat': 47.946666666666665, 'Name': 'A4720', 'Long': -20.0}` times 400 (so it's a big dictionaire)

As i'm making a .dll plug-in, the fewer files that have to be copied with the .dll the better. 
So I'm thinking of declaring a global array of structures or a map in the beginning of the program already filled so that :

->The program doesn't have to search and fill the structures(or map) every time it is executed (the .txt file is immutable)

->The .txt file doesn't need to be alongside the .dll plug-in.

My questions to you:

**1**-Is it a good idea to declare the array already filled? Do i save a little running time by doing it?

**2**-Is an array of strucutres a good idea for this? I know something about array of structures and nothing about map

**3**-I'm thinking of `binary_search` for the search method(still don't know how to return the index of the search with `binary_search` though). Good idea?

I tried searching the web for this problem but i don't quite know how to put my question in order to successfully search it

Comment: If the data is just like that, I would suggest a `map` of `<string, int>`

Comment: It is even more complicated: The key/value pairs have different value types

Comment: Yeah, that's probably a good idea. And also, just saw that `map` has a `find` function that will probably do what i want.
About the first question, what do you think? Should i fill it previously or not?

Comment: @awesomeyi Just checked `map`for the last hour and making a `map`of `<string,double,double>` is not that easy...

Comment: @JoãoPereira how about map<string,tuple<double, double>>?

Comment: I managed to find information on nested maps. So i'm doing `typedef map<double,double> map1` and then `map<string,map1> MAP2`.

But what about that first question.What do you think guys?